# Given a 2D matrix of dates find the range which contains the most of these given dates

Tags: java, arrays, date, multidimensional-array, visitors

**Problem description**

Visitors have an arrival and departure time in the given format: `HH:MM`
This gives each visitor an array in such a format - `[arrive, depart]`
When given a 2 dimensional array containing the information of all the visitors that day, find the range of dates where there are most visitors, aswell as the number of visitors during that time range. If one visitors arrival date is the same as another ones departure date then this is counted as 2 visitors.

**Example**

`visitors = [  [10:10, 10:40], [10:20, 10:50], [10:00, 10:30] ];`

`output: 10:20 - 10:30 , 3`

How can this problem be solved in Java or just mathematically?

Comment: first put here your approach then we can do something solving question for others is not how rhings work here

Comment: If there are no other constraints just take the minimum arrival and the maximum departure times and there you have all the visitors. Also, that's not a 2d array, it's an array of pairs (or, if you want, an array of arrays, but you only have exactly 1 row, so 2d array is a bit misleading as it makes the reader think of a matrix)

Comment: Do not just post some home work assignment and expect SO to do it for you. Make an attempt and post your code.